# Visual Studio 2017 community dotnet.exe crashes

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever i try to debug new dot net core application, dotnet.exe crashes immediately and not able to debug my application. I am getting following detail in output window:

```
The program '[4220] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450750 (0x80008082).
The program '[3468] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Error code 0x80008082 is for CoreHostLibLoadFailure based on what i have searched on internet but not able to found something which provides detail about how to solve this problem. I need help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether solution will work for everyone but i am able to resolve issue by installing update KB2533623. I have windows 7 SP1 32 bit installed my PC.

Comment: You want to accept your answer.