# The program '[3984] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081)

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core-2.0

```
The program '[3984] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081).
The program '[3984] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2492] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7352] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[2492] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

After I started the debugger on my mvc project (Using VS 2017 .Net Core 2.14) the chrome opens and closes for a second during the debugging and I m getting this errors. 
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Fixed by selecting "Native code" in the "Attach to" field of the "Attach to Process" dialog.

For some reason (perhaps an add-on I have installed?) Visual Studio has identified chrome.exe as a process of type "WebKit, x86" on this machine and selected the wrong way to attach.

Link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d79dd68-6131-4c41-8af6-453600c3e19a/vs2013-cannot-attach-to-chromeexe?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Run the latest available .NET Core SDK setup from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md)

**Detailed Explanation:** When I was trying to run a simple .NET Core console application below error was shown in output window and the application wasn't starting:

> The program '[11036] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749
> (0x80008083).

Then I went to **\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\** path of my application code and started a PowerShell window from that path. Then I tried launching the application from console with below command:

```
dotnet .\myapp.dll
```

which gave below error:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not
> found.
>
> - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>   \
> - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.

Then I realized that Visual Studio wasn't showing the actual error in the output window which would have been more useful to me.

So that ring some bells. Then, I ran below command

```
dotnet --version
```

This gave me the version of highest .NET Core version installed on my machine. It returned :

```
2.0.3
```

I also checked **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk** directory and it contained below directories:

```
1.0.0-preview2-003131
1.0.0-preview4-004233
1.0.4
1.1.0
```

Here folder **1.1.2** is missing required by my application to run. So, I ran the latest available .NET Core SDK setup from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md) to repair it. There are two parts of the setup:

1. Microsoft .NET core 1.0.5 runtime
2. Microsoft .NET core Windows Server hosting

The second part is crucial to solving the error we're facing. It requires that IIS feature is enabled on your machine as a prerequisite. So enable IIS feature before you get started with the installer.

So running and finishing the installer setup resolved my issue.

Comment: Good description.

Comment: Thank you! Why IIS / Visual Studio doesn't give me this simple error message is beyond me.

Comment: Also, always check the link for latest frameworks :
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/X.Y
current version is: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Answer (score 4):

I just right click on the project then select properties and change the target framework 
from 1.1 to 1.0. DONE!

[image]

Comment: I had a very similar issue to OP, and this solution worked for me. For my own understanding, why does this fix work? What makes it fix  (0x80008081) issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error to this. In my case I had a NuGet package which targeted a higher minor version of .NET Core than the SDK I had installed locally. To solve, I went down a minor version on the NuGet package, but updating to the latest SDK also probably would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything from "\bin\Debug" path, rebuild the solution and run. Problem solved!

Comment: In my case the problem appeared after a Windows Update & Reboot.  In my case just doing the flush of Bin/debug as mentioned by Jasmin (clean solution is not enough)  fixed the issue.  Note that in the past I had to do some nuget package update but not this time.

Comment: IMPORANT: Note that I also had to delete the .vs folder at the root of my project in addition to the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example, you are using .net core version 2.2.

Please check that:

1. You have installed ".NET Core 2.2" SDK x64 or x86
   version. If not you can download it from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
2. Make sure "2.2.110" folder is generated under below folder structure

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

Answer (score 0):

It is similar issue that I faced and opened the new question. I was looking for answer not `workaround / solution`. So I decided instead of answering my own question so answer here.

**Microsoft Security Advisory: `Insecure library loading could allow remote code execution`**

Microsoft has released new `API enhancements for Windows` to help developers correctly and securely load `external libraries`.

This is nothing to do with alone Visual Studio.

```
LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 0x00000800

 If this value is used, %windows%\system32 is searched
 for the DLL and its dependencies. Directories in the standard
 search path are not searched. This value cannot be combined with
 LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH.

**Effective Platforms are:**
1- Windows 7, 

2 - Windows Server 2008 R2,
 
3- Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008:  This value requires KB2533623 to be installed.

4 - Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  This value is not supported
```

**Important Information:**

1. Name : CoreHostLibLoadFailure
2. Value : 0x80008082
3. Value (signed,32-bit): 2147450750
4. Value (8-bit) : 130
5. Description :

> There was a failure loading a `dependent library`. If any of the hosting
> components calls `LoadLibrary/dlopen` on a dependent library and the
> call fails, this error code is returned. The most common case for this
> failure is if the dependent library is missing some of its
> dependencies (for example the necessary `CRT` is missing on the
> machine), likely corrupt or incomplete install. This error code is
> also returned from `corehost_resolve_component_dependencies` if it's
> called on a **hostpolicy** which has not been initialized via the hosting
> layer. This would typically happen if `coreclr` is loaded directly
> without the hosting layer and then `AssemblyDependencyResolver` is used
> (which is an unsupported scenario).

[References :1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remote-code-execution-486ea436-2d47-27e5-6cb9-26ab7230c704)

[References :2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Refernces : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43025896/visual-studio-2017-community-dotnet-exe-crashes)