# The application to execute does not exist: asp net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microservices

I have an asp net core API application. It ran normally, after a while when running more identity application of this error in debug console.

> The application to execute does not exist:
>   'C:\Dev\git\EmployeeFeedBack\Programmers.Internals\src\Services\Identity\Identity.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Identity.API.dll'
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 9040) exited with code
>   -2147450751. To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when
>   debugging stops. Press any key to close this window . . .

I searched for some more unsuccessful forum solutions

Comment: Based on the path, does the application exist?. Also ensure that Identity.API builds properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program '\[3984\] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672371/the-program-3984-dotnet-exe-has-exited-with-code-2147450751-0x80008081)