# I cant execute console in C#, Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I try to execute the console C# in visual studio 2019 but, the console presents to me this message and I don't know what is it. I installed all extensions and .NET already.

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you execute console in VS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672371/the-program-3984-dotnet-exe-has-exited-with-code-2147450751-0x80008081

Comment: What did you execute in the console？Could you provide any relevant code?

Comment: The screenshot shows two errors, which one are you asking about?